# Lazy range iteration in javascript using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've caught myself using this in place of a traditional for loop:

```
_.each(_.range(count), function(i){
  ...
});
```

The disadvantage being creating an unnecessary array of size count.

Still, i prefer the semantics of, for example, *.each(*.range(10,0,-1), ...); when iterating backwards.

Is there any way to do a lazy iteration over range, as with pythons xrange?

Comment: Any reason not to use a simple for loop?

Comment: i find it easier to see what's going on with range(n,0,-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering the [source of underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js) says the following about `range`:

> Generate an integer Array containing an arithmetic progression

I doubt there is a way to do lazy iteration without modifying the source.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note:

```
_.each(_.range(count), function(i){
  ...
});
```

is equivalent to

```
_.times(count, function(i){
  ...
});
```

small is beautiful...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty, dig into the sources of the older but stable and feature-complete [MochiKit](http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/)'s [Iter](http://mochi.github.com/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/Iter.html) module. It tries to create something along the lines of Python's [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#module-itertools).